# Lodash lib load selected function

Tags: angularjs, lodash, grunt-contrib-concat

Currently we are using lodash in our angularJS project, while building the project using grunt we are doing concat of all such vendor files, issue is currently lodash is getting its all function in the vendor.js(concated single file), is there a way we can do that configurable to get only listed/selected functions which we are using, in the build file.? And we are using node modules to get lodash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know we do in angular 2 and above like this while using webpack, but here we are not using web pack, example
 import { map, tail, times, uniq } from 'lodash';

Comment: have you try to import like this : `import { map } from 'lodash/map';`

Comment: @Yanis-git, thanks for that but in this case we are not using webpack, we are creating a vendor file in which we have all lib loaded in one shot....

Comment: that is why you can't :/ or you create your own `lodash-light.pkg.js`